# How can I store all objects created in a class in a single array returned by that class in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, inner-classes

I am using Java to create an object called Track, which contains a bunch of different numerical objects created by methods in the class (floats, doubles, ints, etc. etc).  This class, Track, will be instantiated multiple times by another class (multiple instances of Track inside a single instance of another class).  I want track to become an array of those number objects so that the parent class will contain multiple Track arrays.

The Track class is structured like this and nested inside another class which will have a loop to instantiate Track as many times as needed.

```
class Track
{
    public int trackID()
    {
    }

    public short trackValidity()
   {
   }

  ....//other objects
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you normally declare arrays, for example:

```
Track[] track = new Track[42];
track[0] = new Track();
```

Or as full working example:

```
public class ObjectArray {

    Track[] track;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ObjectArray tester = new ObjectArray();
        tester.setIt();
        tester.getIt();
    }

    public void setIt(){
        track = new Track[42];
        for(int i=0; i<42; i++){
            track[i]= new Track(i);
            track[i].calcProduct(i, i+1);
        }
    }

    public void getIt(){
        for(int i=0; i<track.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Track "+track[i].getSerial()+" has product: "+track[i].getProduct());
        }
    }

    class Track{
        private int serial;
        private int product;

        Track(int i){
            serial = i;
        }

        public void calcProduct(int a, int b){
            product = a*b;
        }

        public int getSerial() {
            return serial;
        }

        public int getProduct() {
            return product;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would I tell it to put the values of  public short trackValidity()
   {
   }  or other objects in that array?

Comment: Do you need to save the whole Track-instance or do you need only one variable? In the first case you get it with `track[0].trackValidity();`. The second case should maybe use something different than an array of Track-instances. Remember that java uses reference variables, so for every calculation you should use a `new Track()`-instance

Comment: This makes a lot sense actually. I can't test it as I am just writing the scaffolding for the code (most of the methods are currently empty), but this looks like it should work).

Comment: For some reason Track[] track = new Track[42]; is not being liked.

Comment: @cluemein What is the problem? I added an full working example, so you can have a better look.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, you can make a function to build a array of objets with number objects:

```
public ArrayList getNumbers(){
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
    array.add(trackID());
    array.add(trackValidity());
    ...
    return array;
}
```

Remember to cast the object when u get it from the array, for example at pos 0 (trackID) is an int so when you get it from the arraylist dont forget to cast it:

```
Track myTrack = new Track();
//set track variables ...
ArrayList trackInfo = myTrack.getNumbers();
int trackID = (int) trackInfo.get(0);
```

Comment: Would this method be inside the Track class or the parent class (outer class)?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now.  It would make Track act like its own method that ultimately returns the array to the parent class right?

Comment: Its like a serialization, you can convert whole variables of your object into an array of objects. You will have the problem to cast them, knowing what object is inside each position.
Also you can make your own deserialize function to set each Track value from an array of objects.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not very familiar with serialization/deserialization.  I have heard of it, but never really read up on it or knowingly used it.

Comment: I wish I could make both your answers the accepted answer, because both look like they would work.  The reason I'm going with the other one is because it looks a bit simpler (I could be wrong though).

Comment: No problem, if you just need and array of tracks at ur parent class, @ctst option will be the answer. If you need your track object to return his interal variables into an array, you will need my method. Hope this helps u.